# Determine button state, Clicked(Active) or not MS Dynamics AX

Tags: axapta, x++

how is it possible to determine button state in AX? Clicked or not? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The is a `clicked` method you can overwrite on your button. 
On you button control, expand the node and right click the `Methods` node. 
From the list of available methods, select the `clicked` method.

A method will be added where you can add your code:

```
void clicked()
{
    super();
}
```

This method is triggered when the button is clicked. You can also call this method to execute is from code.

Normally when you click a button the `gotFocus` method is executed. 
When you call the clicked event in code, it isn't, so in your case you can manually call the `setfocus` method before you execute the clicked method. If you override the `gotFocus` method you can set a Boolean to store that value. Override the `lostFocus` method to reset your value. You second button will keep the focus, so you might want to set the focus back to your first button by calling the `setFocus` method again.

I don't know of an other way you could do this. But you shouldn't really be doing this either... There is something wrong with your requirement.

Comment: thanks for answer Klass. here is my situation: there is a button 'A' and when I click this button I need to determine the state of button 'B'. for example pseudocode
if(ButtonB.IsClicked)
{
//do something
}

Comment: How can button B be clicked if you just clicked on button A? Do you mean if it has ever been clicked? Or that it's selected or something,

Comment: It's a bit of a strange request. You should review the solution you came up with or even the requirement. Not once did I have such a request and I wouldn't do it if it was asked of me either I think. But anyway, I updated my comment with a method that may work for you.

Comment: what? how can you click 2 buttons at once?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the `FormButtonControl.mouseDown()` method?

See here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa858380(v=ax.50).aspx

And see here for other button methods:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa857432(v=ax.50).aspx